# How to get HTTP request string from HttpURLConnection instance

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

I have HttpURLConnection instance created from URL and also I set query parameters and called some setters on this HttpURLConnection instance. I use this instance to get response from web service.

Is there some way to get the HTTP request string that will be sent over the network when using the given HttpURLConnection instance ? (just for debugging purposes). Can we do this programatically using HttpURLConnection or if it's not possible how can I monitor the outgoing HTTP traffic ?

The reason I need this that in some cases it can be easier to detect what is wrong with your configuration of HttpURLConnection by looking directly at the request that is defined by this instance than trying to figure out what is wrong with particular configuration of HttpURLConnection by checking what setters was called.

Thank you for any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can monitor your `http Traffic` by using **Fiddler**

Here is the download [link](http://fiddler2.com/get-fiddler)